# minimizing lock scope for JDK8 ConcurrentHashMap check-and-set operation

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, concurrenthashmap, atomic

1.

I have multiple threads updating a ConcurrentHashMap. 
Each thread appends a list of integers to the Value of a map entry based on the key. 
There is no removal operation by any thread.

**The main point here is that I want to minimize the scope of locking and synchronization as much as possible.**

I saw that the doc of computeIf...() method says "Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress", which is not so encouraging. On the other hand, when I look into its source code, I failed to observe where it locks/synchronizes on the entire map.

Therefore, I wonder about the **comparison of theoretical performance** of using computeIf...() and the following home-grown 'method 2'.

2.

Also, I feel that the problem I described here is perhaps one of the **most simplified check-n-set (or generally a 'compound') operation you can carry out on ConcurrentHashMap**.

Yet I'm not quite confident and **can't quite find much guideline** about how to do even this kind of simple compound operations on ConcurrentHashMap, **without Locking/Synchronizing on the entire map**.

So any general good practice advice for this will be much appreciated.

```
public void myConcurrentHashMapTest1() {

    ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<Integer>> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<Integer>>();

    // MAP KEY: a Word found by a thread on a page of a book 
    String myKey = "word1";

    // -- Method 1: 
    // Step 1.1 first, try to use computeIfPresent(). doc says it may lock the
    //      entire myMap. 
    myMap.computeIfPresent(myKey, (key,val) -> val.addAll(getMyVals()));
    // Step 1.2 then use computeIfAbsent(). Again, doc says it may lock the
    //      entire myMap. 
    myMap.computeIfAbsent(myKey, key -> getMyVals());    
}

public void myConcurrentHashMapTest2() {        
    // -- Method 2: home-grown lock splitting (kind of). Will it theoretically 
    //      perform better? 

    // Step 2.1: TRY to directly put an empty list for the key
    //      This may have no effect if the key is already present in the map
    List<Integer> myEmptyList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    myMap.putIfAbsent(myKey, myEmptyList);

    // Step 2.2: By now, we should have the key present in the map
    //      ASSUMPTION: no thread does removal 
    List<Integer> listInMap = myMap.get(myKey);

    // Step 2.3: Synchronize on that list, append all the values 
    synchronized(listInMap){
        listInMap.addAll(getMyVals());
    }

}

public List<Integer> getMyVals(){
    // MAP VALUE: e.g. Page Indices where word is found (by a thread)
    List<Integer> myValList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    myValList.add(1);
    myValList.add(2);

    return myValList;
}
```

Comment: Generally speaking, it doesn't lock the entire map but just a _segment_ of the map.

Comment: The locking is pessimistic, not optimistic, so you should pre-screen both approaches with a get.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks! if u were also talking about JDK8, in the e.g. computeIfAbsent(), I assume u r referring to what's in the for {... else{...synchronized (f)...}} ?

Comment: @BenManes thanks! but sorry, I don't quite get when u said "you should pre-screen both approaches with a get"

Comment: @LouisWasserman Sorry to continue my comment for u, if that's the only 'locking', i.e. on individual 'bin' only, why do u say 'Generally speaking', and similarly why the javadoc of the method also claims 'Some attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while computation is in progress' ?  Thanks again

Comment: @Stochastika A "read, if absent compute-if-absent" avoids locking the bin to determine if the entry is present. Instead most reads will find the existing value with a small amount of locking when not found and computed. This can greatly [improve performance](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Benchmarks#compute).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're basing your assumption (that using `ConcurrentHashMap` as intended will be too slow for you) on a misinterpretation of the Javadoc. The Javadoc doesn't state that the whole map will be locked. It also doesn't state that each `computeIfAbsent()` operation performs pessimistic locking.

What could actually be locked is a bin (a.k.a. bucket) which corresponds to a single element in the internal array backing of the `ConcurrentHashMap`. Note that this is not Java 7's map segment containing multiple buckets. When such a bin is locked, potentially blocked operations are solely updates for keys that hash to the same bin.

On the other hand, your solution doesn't mean that all internal locking within `ConcurrentHashMap` is avoided - `computeIfAbsent()` is just one of the methods that can degrade to using a `synchronized` block while updating. Even the `putIfAbsent()` with which you're initially putting an empty list for some key, can block if it doesn't hit an empty bin.

What's worse though is that your solution doesn't guarantee the visibility of your `synchronized` bulk updates. You are guaranteed that a `get()` *happens-before* a `putIfAbsent()` which value it observes, but there's no *happens-before* between your bulk updates and a subsequent `get()`.

P.S. You can read further about the locking in `ConcurrentHashMap` in its OpenJDK implementation: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java, lines 313-352.

Comment: Thanks Dimitar! I'll surely read through the OpenJDK doc and code. 1. do u mean that even for the **current thread** the 'listInMap' in my 2nd method can still be **null**, as from the 2nd last paragraph of your comment? 2. when u mentioned about "degrading ...", is it like for example the part in computeIfAbsent():  '**for {... else{...synchronized (f)...}}**' in the Oracle JDK8? 3. In fact, I'm a bit confused about that code. To me, it almost looks like doing some work even after it found the entry is **NOT** Absent which a bit contradicting to 'computeIfAbsent'?

Comment: 1. The thread that calls `putIfAbsent()` with an empty list cannot see a `null` value for that key later (unless a concurrent `remove()` occurred).  However using your scheme, other threads doing `get()` for that same key much later may see just the empty list each time, without seeing what you've added. In practice, with strong memory model architectures, this may happen very rarely, but it's still a valid issue. 2. Yep, exactly. 3. You're mixing the existence of items hashing to the same bin, and items with the exact same key. Look how the `onlyIfAbsent` flag is being used.

Comment: Thanks Dimitar! upvoted the comment and marked the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As already [explained by Dimitar Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36635633/2711488), a `compute…` method doesn’t generally lock the entire map. In the best case, i.e. there’s no need to increase the capacity and there’s no hash collision, only the mapping for the single key is locked.

However, there are still things you can do better:

- generally, avoid performing multiple lookups. This applies to both variants, using `computeIfPresent` followed by `computeIfAbsent`, as well as using `putIfAbsent` followed by `get`
- it’s still recommended to minimize the code executed when holding a lock, i.e. don’t invoke `getMyVals()` while holding the lock as it doesn’t depend on the map’s state

Putting it together, the update should look like:

```
// compute without holding a lock
List<Integer> toAdd=getMyVals();
// update the map
myMap.compute(myKey, (key,val) -> {
    if(val==null) val=toAdd; else val.addAll(toAdd);
    return val;
});
```

or

```
// compute without holding a lock
List<Integer> toAdd=getMyVals();
// update the map
myMap.merge(myKey, toAdd, (a,b) -> { a.addAll(b); return a; });
```

which can be simplified to

```
myMap.merge(myKey, getMyVals(), (a,b) -> { a.addAll(b); return a; });
```

Comment: Thanks Holger! Upvoted. merge() is on my favorite list from this day onwards.

Comment: One more question, @Holger, to my point 2 in the original question, in term of general approach to this kind of compound action for ConcurrentHashMap, for the solution u presented above, it should also work for the situation even if the other thread may be doing entry removal from the map?

Comment: *Especially* when removing, it works smoothly. Note that when you perform a plain `get`, you’ll get a reference to a stored list and for using that list, you need a different measure to prevent concurrent updates (e.g. you can do it when you know for sure that all writer threads are done). In contrast, retrieving a list via `remove` *guarantees* that there will be no concurrent updates as subsequent update operations will create a new list.